# Excel multiple IF AND OR Conditions

Tags: excel, if-statement

I am trying to make a status condition. Below is are the cells that I want to have a status with. I have 2 columns, Case Status and Bug Status

```
Sheet1
cell#   Case Status    Bug Status
G8      Passed
G9      Failed         Fixed
G10     Failed         Pending
G11     New Bug
G12     New Bug        Fixed
```

On the other (Sheet2) I want to know the general status of sheet1, if it is still "Open" or "Closed". My parameters would be, all "Failed" and "New Bug" case status should a corresponding "Fixed" status under Bug status column inorder to have a "Closed" status under sheet2 general status.

Any help will greatly appreciated. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are a couple ways:

The first uses COUNTIFS:

```
=IF(COUNTIFS(G8:G12,"=Failed",H8:H12,"<>Fixed")+COUNTIFS(G8:G12,"=New Bug",H8:H12,"<>Fixed"),"Open","Closed")
```

And the second is an array formula (so you need to use Control-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when you put it in):

```
=IF(SUM((G8:G12="Failed")*(H8:H12<>"Fixed")+(G8:G12="New Bug")*(H8:H12<>"Fixed")),"Open","Closed")
```